# How to get manually assigned parent's id which is not bound yet?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have two entities

child entity:

```
class Currency(db.Model):    
    country = db.ReferenceProperty(Country)
    #...
```

parent entity:

```
class Country(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    #...
```

I manually assign `country` to `currency` with appcfg.py upload_data from `Currency.cvs` file

When I type at console, `currency.country.key`, I get this error message:

`ReferencePropertyResolveError: ReferenceProperty failed to be resolved: [u'Country', 60L]`

how can I get this id of country which is not bound yet?

Additionally, this is how it looks like at datastore panel Currency entity

```
Entity Kind     Currency
Entity Key      ahBkZXZ-ZmluZHlvdXJyb29tchALEghDdXJyZW5jeRiw_wEM 
country(Key)    ahBkZXZ-ZmluZHlvdXJyb29tcg0LEgdDb3VudHJ5GDwM
                                   Country: id=60
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume by "not bound", you mean that the relevant record hasn't been loaded. You can get the key of a `ReferenceProperty` with `Currency.country.get_value_for_datastore(currency_instance)`.